# Yammer questions

Tags: support, asking-questions, close-reasons

Now that there's more [tighter integration between SharePoint and Yammer](http://www.zdnet.com/microsoft-adds-more-e-mail-sharepoint-integration-to-yammer-7000021997/) - how should Yammer-related questions be addressed? Should they be referred to the [Yammer Support forums](http://community.office365.com/en-us/wikis/yammer/default.aspx) or other [Yammer public sites](http://community.office365.com/en-us/forums/176.aspx) ?

Comment: I would personally love to see them answered here in the SharePoint forum. As Microsoft is not backing down with Yammer and the integration between the two products becomes thighter I believe that this is the correct venue.

Comment: FM - thanks.. the MS enterprise social networking space is still evolving and not quite clear (yet). I have seen some posts that puts SP 2013 Social computing features against  Yammer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We already have a [yammer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yammer) tag, with five questions. So fire away - ask your yammer questions, as long as they are related to SharePoint. Otherwise, you'd have better chances at the yammer forums you mention.

Answer (score 4):

SharePoint and Yammer seems to be more and more merged together in what Microsoft refer to as their "Social Layer" that will span most of their products.

To me I would therefore gladly see questions about Yammer posted here on SP.SE, it is surely within the scope of the community and I bet that many of out members has valuable knowledge regarding it :)