# Updating "Help Center > Asking" regarding Yammer

Tags: discussion

For the first time I personally have seen today [a Yammer related question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/159184/yammer-configuration-activate-yammer-with-powershell) on SP.SE and wondered if they were off-topic.

As they are [not considered off-topic in general](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/a/994/18923), would it be helpful to update the [Help Center > Asking](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page regarding Yammer (similar to InfoPath related questions)?

> We accept questions about the SharePoint platform. This is defined as the functionality within:
>
> - the SharePoint server range of products (i.e. SharePoint Foundation and Server, Windows SharePoint Services, SharePoint Portal Server)
> - SharePoint Designer
> - InfoPath where it integrates with SharePoint
> - **Yammer where it integrates with SharePoint**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Makes sense to me, updated the Help Center information.